# Substitute src img in href of link

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var wrap = $('<a class="fancybox" href=""></a>').appendTo(li);

var img = $('<img/>').appendTo(wrap);
```

What to write here href="" in string `var wrap = $('<a class="fancybox" href=""></a>').appendTo(li);` ?

Comment: you have to write the path of the link like `href="www.mylink.com"`

Comment: I need point src of img for href of link.

Comment: But you haven't set the `src` property yet!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this:

```
   var wrap = $('<a class="fancybox" href=""></a>').appendTo(li);

   var img = $('<img src="YOUR_IMAGE_URL" />').appendTo(wrap);

    $(wrap).attr('href', $(img).attr('src'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to understand you but is it what you want ?

```
var wrap = $('<a class="fancybox" href="myimage.jpg"></a>').appendTo(li);
var img = $('<img/>').appendTo(wrap);
img.attr('src',wrap.attr('href'));
```

Comment: I need something like this, but it does not work.
`var wrap = $('<a class="fancybox" href=""></a>').appendTo(li);
 var img = $('<img/>').appendTo(wrap);

 wrap.attr('href',img.attr('src'));`